# from Form Responses to another Sheet's last row and capable to overwrite in the future

Tags: google-apps-script

Can somebody help me with my script. Its been quite sometime now and I still can't able to pull off what I want.

**Script's Purpose:** To transfer values from Form Responses (sheet) to Tracker (sheet) OnFormSubmit.
Then the entries from Form should be transferred on the last row/blank row every time. Then when the value is already transferred to Tracker it can be overwrite/updated if needed any time.

So whenever we have new entry from Form, the other value that's been altered should not be fixed with the transferred entries only.
Please see my initial script:

````
var lastrow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow() //Gets last row from form responses
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange("C" + lastrow).getValue() // gets the value from column C and last row
var lastrowts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker").getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()
var ts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker").getRange("C" + lastrowts).setValue(ss) // sets the value from ss
}
//function onFormSubmit(e) {
//var form = FormApp.openById("1FAIpQLScnJT1KEXiMvinZZ5LyIDG-l8FJcdeaGzU3MmTkshYNA4lcww")
//var formResponses = form.getResponses();
//for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
//var formResponse = formResponses[i];
//var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
//for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
//var itemResponse = itemResponses[j].getResponse();
//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker")
//Logger.log(itemResponse)
//ss.appendRow([itemResponse])
//}
//}
//}```
````

Comment: Are you using the form trigger or the spreadsheet trigger?

Comment: When you say transfer values do you mean copy and paste or cut and paste?

Answer (score 0):

If you interested in the data from the linked spreadsheet then this should do the trick:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  const sh=e.source.getSheetByName('Tracker');
  sh.appendRow(e.values);
}
```

There's often more information in an event object than is described in the documentation.  And I usually check it with something like this:

```
e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').setValue(JSON.Stringify(e));
```

Just stick that somewhere in your function in the beginning to remind yourself what parameters you have to play with.  I usually usually just copy the header line in the response sheet and copy to the sheet I'm going to append to.  You can do it in code if you prefer but I usually take the path of least resistance.